# Google Photos API single user

Tags: google-photos

I'm so excited about the API, but I want to use the API differently. Currently from what I've understood, the API can be used where each user of my app will have to consent and upload his/her photos to my app (using his Google account) and my app can use his photos under his consent (through Google Photos API towards his/her account).

I want to manage the users (locally created) through my APP and let them upload the necessary photos from their PC (non-google accounts) to my app  which will be saving these photos directly to my single defined google photos account from where I can retrieve the photos to my app and share.

Is this approach possible?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a use case that's supported by the Google Photos Library API.

You could create an album in your user's Google Photos library, upload the photos into their account and add them to this album, which you could then share with your account through the API.

However, if you are after a centralized repository where your users can upload media to your application, [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage/) would be a better fit. You can find the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) to get started. You might also need to integrate [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to handle user authentication and to authorize access to this data.